# What does "pc’d" mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

I read on https://redd.it/q75w0s:

> Travel rewards can only get a 1.5 c/pt (plus any preferred rewards increases) redemption rate when redeeming for travel or dining statement credits (a feature like Chase PYB) and a 1 c/pt redemption as a general statement credit, versus Unlimited Cash Rewards you get 1.5% cash back as a flat rate (or in your case 2.62). **I actually just pc’d my travel rewards to an unlimited cash.** It is simply a more versatile card. Keep in mind that the travel rewards card has no FTF whereas the Unlikited Cash does

What does "pc’s" mean? I'm guessing replacing, but I wonder what it is standing for. I couldn't find it on Google.

Comment: Why are you asking us, instead of the person who wrote it?

Comment: @ColleenV I prefer SE over Reddit.

Comment: @ColleenV (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342245/178179)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about someone's informal expression on Reddit.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/credit-cards/credit-card-product-change used the same term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PC = product change. It is a term used when changing credit cards within the same provider.

https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/credit-cards/credit-card-product-change:

> You can ask the issuer to "product change" your existing credit card to a different version within the issuer's portfolio.

Comment: I would agree, and suggest that **I just pc's my [card]** is a typo for **I just pc'*d* my [card]** — i.e. "I just product-changed my card."

Comment: Yes, "pc'*d*" is used in the linked Reddit page. I edited the question to reflect. And in case it's not clear to anyone, a "*'d*" suffix is a common (if typographically suspect) way of turning abbreviations and other unwieldy things into past-tense verbs ("I TP'd their house").